# Lowercase everything until end of group

Tags: cases, text-manipulation

What'd be the most efficient way of lowercasing everything from the point of the command invocation until the end of the group, that is, how should one define a command that acts like, for example, `{\scshape ... }`, just lowering the case of everything that follows. Let's for the beginning say that what follows is just plain text.
(also wondering if LaTeX3 will make such text, or text+commands, manipulations any easier?)

Comment: Thanks David. It does seem like a duplicate.  So you're saying there are no smart barely legal ways of accomplishing this? Some recursive command eating characters one by one?

Comment: yes you can iterate over the characters 1 by 1 (although doing it for general tex markup is tricky) if you have enough control over the input that you can be sure it is just plain text then 9 times out of 10 you have enough control to make sure it is lowercase anyway.